# Dependency walker on cygwin app gives conflicting information?

Tags: linker, cygwin, dependency-walker, missing-symbols

I am using the dependency walker to figure out why my link of a cygwin ported application is not correct.

It states that cgywin1.dll is missing the following symbols:

```
AddAtomA
FindAtomA
GetAtomNameA
GetModuleHandleA
```

http://wkf.thruhere.net/Hosting/undefined.png

Looking around, I see that these are supposed to come from -lkernel32 on the link line, which I have added at the end, however, dependency walker still shows these symbols as missing, yet it also lists kernel32.dll below and shows these symbols as being defined in there.

http://wkf.thruhere.net/Hosting/defined.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without -lkernel32. There should be no need to provide that explicitly because it's automatically linked in. Providing it on the link line might be messing up the link order.